# JsonConvert.SerializeObject() fails in serializing class with DateTime fields

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, json.net

I'm having a class with only private fields and their public getter-setters. I need to convert class object into JSON String hence I'm using JSON.Net.

Following is a simple snippet to convert class object into a JSON string.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

But the method `SerializeObject` throws `StackOverflowException` at field in `MyClass` of type `DateTime`. What's happening here?

**Update**

Following is how `MyClass` looks like (as it is, I don't mind sharing the actual class)

```
    class MyClass
    {
        private int _Model;
        public int Model
        {
            get
            {
                return _Model;
            }
            set
            {
                _Model = value;
            }
        }

        private long _ProductionControlNumber;
        public long ProductionControlNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return _ProductionControlNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                _ProductionControlNumber = value;
            }
        }

        private DateTime _ProductionDate;
        public DateTime ProductionDate
        {
            get
            {
                return _ProductionDate;
            }
            set
            {
                _ProductionDate = value;
            }
        }

        private DateTime _TestDate;
        public DateTime TestDate
        {
            get
            {
                return _TestDate;
            }
            set
            {
                _TestDate = value;
            }
        }

        private DateTime _TestStartTime;
        public DateTime TestStartTime
        {
            get
            {
                return _TestStartTime;
            }
            set
            {
                _TestStartTime = value;
            }
        }

        private TimeSpan _TestDuration;
        public TimeSpan TestDuration
        {
            get
            {
                return _TestDuration;
            }
            set
            {
                _TestDuration = value;
            }
        }

        public DateTime TestEndTime
        {
            get
            {
                //TODO Perform start end time computing logic.
                return TestEndTime;
            }
        }

        private int _TestBed;
        public int TestBed
        {
            get
            {
                return _TestBed;
            }
            set
            {
                _TestBed = value;
            }
        }

        private long _EngineSerial;
        public long EngineSerial
        {
            get
            {
                return _EngineSerial;
            }
            set
            {
                _EngineSerial = value;
            }
        }

        private Single _FuelSpecificGravity;
        public Single FuelSpecificGravity
        {
            get
            {
                return _FuelSpecificGravity;
            }
            set
            {
                _FuelSpecificGravity = value;
            }
        }

        private long _FuelConsume100;
        public long FuelConsume100
        {
            get
            {
                return _FuelConsume100;
            }
            set
            {
                _FuelConsume100 = value;
            }
        }

        private long _FuelConsume110;
        public long FuelConsume110
        {
            get
            {
                return _FuelConsume100;
            }
            set
            {
                _FuelConsume100 = value;
            }
        }

        private int _TemporaryRPM;
        public int TemporaryRPM
        {
            get
            {
                return _TemporaryRPM;
            }
            set
            {
                _TemporaryRPM = value;
            }
        }

        private int _PermanentRPM;
        public int PermanentRPM
        {
            get
            {
                return _PermanentRPM;
            }
            set
            {
                _PermanentRPM = value;
            }
        }

        private Single _RatedPower;
        public Single RatedPower
        {
            get
            {
                return _RatedPower;
            }
            set
            {
                _RatedPower = value;
            }
        }

        private int _RatedSpeed;
        public int RatedSpeed
        {
            get
            {
                return _RatedSpeed;
            }
            set
            {
                _RatedSpeed = value;
            }
        }

        private double _PulleyDiameter;
        public double PulleyDiameter
        {
            get
            {
                return _PulleyDiameter;
            }
            set
            {
                _PulleyDiameter = value;
            }
        }

        private double _RopeDiameter;
        public double RopeDiameter
        {
            get
            {
                return _RopeDiameter;
            }
            set
            {
                _RopeDiameter = value;
            }
        }

        private Single _FullLoad;
        public Single FullLoad
        {
            get
            {
                return _FullLoad;
            }
            set
            {
                _FullLoad = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I'll have another class which will have `MyClass` type field (along with its own similar set of fields), which is going to be converted into JSON string too, and that shouldn't be a problem since JSON.Net is said to support that situation too.

**Note:** I'm new to C# but I've previously worked with JSON in Java, where I get to play with `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`, and they were pretty straight forward.

Comment: Could you also show us `MyClass`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your TestEndTime property's getter references itself. Therefore when Json.NET tries to serialize it, it recursively accesses itself and causes the StackOverflowException.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! that was exactly the problem, I've created private field for `TestEndTime` and similar getter-setter for it and works fine now.

Comment: I think it is better to use auto-properties in C# as of 3.0 if there is no specific reason for a private variable. This type of mistypings will not occur with that method.